# Equivalent yum command for `apt-get install -y packagename --no-upgrade`

Tags: centos, installation, yum, apt, package-management

I was using this command in a shell script on my ubuntu server `apt-get install -y packagename  --no-upgrade` . It will install the package if it is not already present. It will not upgrade the package. Now I want to migrate it to a centos machine. I couldn't find any switch equivalent to `--no-upgrade` in yum. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option for `yum`.
You will have to work around it with something like this:

```
rpm --quiet -q packagename || yum -y install packagename
```